# viranode project

Tags: push-technology

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdkdshjdfg hdj.fbdfhhfsdf vvnvbnv vmvn vnmbndsjkfjksdfposdfdsfsfdf

Comment: Is this in the browser, or using "react native" on the server? You cannot use the MongoDB Node driver library in a browser client.

Comment: This is in the browser.So if I want to insert data how can i do that?

Comment: Yeah, you want to talk to a REST interface or similar service and not to MongoDB directly. There are plenty of solutions out there, or build your own in your language of choice. Too broad to cover here.

Comment: can you suggest me a tutorial for that sir?

Comment: Closing as a duplicate to a placeholder response here. There is a listing within the MongoDB documentation which is also linked there to various pre-built options, and even a couple of tutorials.

Comment: Also ( keep meaning to bookmark this ) - There also is a downloadable form which combines a couple of blog posts from the MongoDB site. [The Modern Application Stack - MEAN, MERN, and More](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/the-modern-application-stack-mean-mern-and-more) is a PDF download covering front-end and back-end integration and a few more topics. Opinionated, but a reasonable starter for introduction.